# How to replace value for a specific key in json file using python language

Tags: python, json

Json file

```
{
  "payloadFormatVersion": "9.0",
  "payload": {
    "ServiceConfiguration": {
      "LoggingSettings": {
        "NumberOfLogFilesToKeep": 7,
        "LogFileSizeBytes": 0,
        "LogFolderPath": "C:\\demo\\logs\\feature\\",
        "EnvironmentType": "testingenv",
        "DataRelayLogSink": {
          
          "PeriodInSeconds": 60,
          "TargetAddress": "http://localhost:portNumber/dumm1",
          "TargetTokenAddress": "http://localhost:portnumber/token",
          "PayloadType": "somedata",
          "TokenCredentials": {
            "ClientId": "testclientid",
            "ClientSecret": "testclientsecret",
            "GrantType": "testgranttype"
          }
        }
      },
      }
      }
```

[JSON Content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWILZ.png)

```
def repalcejsonForSpecificKey(keyPath,fileName):
    filePath = "C:\\rajesh\\Configurations\\" + fileName + "\\" + fileName + ".json"
    print(filePath)
    Dict = {}
    with open(filePath) as f:
        superHeroSquad = json.load(f)
        duplicatedict={}
        duplicatedict=superHeroSquad
        testDict=getDictonaryItems(keyPath[0],**superHeroSquad)
        print(testDict)
```

```
def getDictonaryItems(searchKey, duplicatedict):
        if searchKey in duplicatedict.keys():
            testDict = duplicatedict[searchKey]
        return testDict
```

```
keyPath = ["payload","ServiceConfiguration", "TokenSettings", "ClientId"]
fileName="vestas.sdh.dr.gateway"
repalcejsonForSpecificKey(keyPath,fileName)
```

Below is my plan

1. Method1 accepts 2 arguments JsonParsingKeyWhereToBereplaced, filename
2. Redirecting Json file to dictionary
3. call the method2 recursively where it accepts 2 arguments, one with searchKey and other is dictonary, this method will return all the key&values from specific Key passed on the method call
   Recursively call this method until and unless you reach downstream key and update the value if found

Trying to update nested value from Json file using python language

**Note:** I was able to update the value in the Json file directly with below line

```
superHeroSquad ['payload']['ServiceConfiguration']['TokenSettings']['ClientId'] = "text"
```

But not like below

```
superHeroSquad[keyPath[0][keyPath[1]][keyPath[2]][keyPath[3]] = "text"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could traverse your **json** as a map and replace the specific values like this:

```py
import json


def replace_json_for_specific_key(file: str, key_pairs: dict[str, any]):
    content = json.load(open(file))

    for k, v in key_pairs.items():
        keys = k.split(".")
        element = content
        for key in keys[:-1]:
            element = element.setdefault(key, {})
        element[keys[-1]] = v

    tmp_file = open(file, "w")
    json.dump(content, tmp_file)
    tmp_file.flush()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    replace_json_for_specific_key(
        "input.json",
        {
            "payload.ServiceConfiguration.LoggingSettings.NumberOfLogFilesToKeep": 90,
            "payload.ServiceConfiguration.LoggingSettings.DataRelayLogSink.TokenCredentials.ClientId": "anothervalue"
        }
    )
```

Notice it will allow you to replace several values at once. You'll need to pass the dot (.) separated path to the specific key.

Comment: -Jorge Alberto Díaz Orozco, Sorry for delay, Thanks for the code, will update my script and check the behavior.

Comment: @-Jorge Alberto Díaz Orozco Receiving below error when running
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\pythonProject\customLibraries\UpdateJsonFile.py", line 2, in <module>
    def replace_json_for_specific_key(file: str, key_pairs: dict[str, str]):
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

Comment: This might be related to the python version you are using. I made this with Python 3.11.